# Wireless does not work 12.10

Tags: wireless, 12.10, broadcom

My primary issue is that my wireless does not work after I installed 12.10.

The output to rfkill list all:

```
5: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

The output to lshw -class network is:

```
*-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 12
   serial: 00:21:9b:d6:46:51
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:44 memory:fe8fc000-fe8fffff ioport:de00(size=256)    
*-network
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
   resources: irq:17 memory:fe7fc000-fe7fffff
```

The output to lspci -nn for the pertinent information is:

```
0b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
```

Thus, it seems the solution would be to run:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

However, I do not currently have access to an ethernet connection, as I am currently only able to use verizon wireless 3g internet.

Thus, is there a way to set up ICS with a Vista machine so that I can access the internet by using the Vista machine as the host? Or, is it possible to fix this by downloading the  important packages in vista and moving them to ubuntu via USB drive?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by dowloading this deb , and installing it :

- [wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb](http://jas.gemnetworks.com/debian/pool/main/w/wireless-bcm43142/wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb)

Double click-it, then open your Terminal and type this command `sudo modprobe wl` , now take off your wired cable and it will work fine.